# How to reset profile-stored data in Bixby

Tags: bixby

If you have data in your capsule that has the feature:

```
features {
  profile-stored {
    max (One)
  }
}
```

how can you reset that feature once stored? (clicked 'yes' to save for later in the simulator)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot erase the stored value, but by using the same utterance, you can replace it with a new value.

For example, **set location to Cupertino** will set a property location with feature profile-stored.

Another utterance **set location to New York City** will replace the stored value to **New York City**